# Magento2 issue Cannot process definition to array for type enum

Tags: magento2, attributes

```
<pre>Array
(
    [name] => status
    [default] => 'enabled'
    [type] => enum
    [nullable] => 0
    [definition] => enum('enabled','disabled')
    [extra] => 
    [comment] => 
)
Cannot process definition to array for type enum
```

Not sure how am I suppose ro solve this issue? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

One of the database table columns has been defined in your custom module or a third-party module that defines the data type `enum` is not allowed in Magento 2.

To solve this issue, you need to find which column in which table has that definition to replace the data type from `enum` to `varchar` or `text`.
You can detect which column in which table has that definition easily with `grep` command, run this command in the Magento root directory:

```
grep -rn "enum(" app/code/ vendor
```

For more information about allowed data types in Magento 2, you can check `definitionPrecessors` argument's item in `app/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\DefinitionAggregator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="definitionProcessors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="boolean" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Boolean</item>
            <item name="int" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Integer</item>
            <item name="smallint" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Integer</item>
            <item name="tinyint" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Integer</item>
            <item name="bigint" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Integer</item>
            <item name="decimal" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Real</item>
            <item name="float" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Real</item>
            <item name="double" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Real</item>
            <item name="text" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Blob</item>
            <item name="blob" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Blob</item>
            <item name="mediumblob" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Blob</item>
            <item name="longblob" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Blob</item>
            <item name="mediumtext" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Blob</item>
            <item name="longtext" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Blob</item>
            <item name="datetime" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Timestamp</item>
            <item name="date" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Date</item>
            <item name="timestamp" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Timestamp</item>
            <item name="char" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\StringBinary</item>
            <item name="varchar" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\StringBinary</item>
            <item name="binary" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\StringBinary</item>
            <item name="varbinary" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\StringBinary</item>
            <item name="json" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Columns\Json</item>
            <item name="index" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Index</item>
            <item name="unique" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Constraints\Internal</item>
            <item name="primary" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Constraints\Internal</item>
            <item name="constraint" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Constraints\Internal</item>
            <item name="reference" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\Definition\Constraints\ForeignKey</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
</type>
```

This solution is applicable for similar data types which are not allowed in Magento 2 (above list), eg: `tinytext`, `time`, `mediumint`, `bit`, **etc**.